# How to hide alias column in SQL Output?

Tags: ms-access-2007

as example, I've the following SQL query ( using Access 2007 )

```
SELECT ID, FirstMaturityDate, PayMentDate,
       iif(PayMentDate>FirstMaturityDate, PayMentDate, FirstMaturityDate)
           as Maxdate
  from Table 1
```

Actually, I need the alias Maxdate for further processing, but I
don't want to to see Maxdate  as column in output. Is this somehow
possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify how you output the data - if you show it in a form or listbox (for example), just don't display the Maxdate column.
(for example, by just not putting a textbox for it on the form)

Comment: i want to execute SQL query in Access but with show this column

Comment: So you don't want to show the query result on a form or a report, but you just want to run an Access query and hide this column? Then you have to create another query which returns the first query without the Maxdate column.

Answer (score 1):

Create a view that includes all the columns except the column you want to hide.

Comment: i want to use it in processing but not show it after SQL query execution